# How can I repair fence rail that is away from the post?

Tags: fence

The gap between the fence rail and fence post/bracket is greater than what it should be. Not sure if the rail was ever connected to the bracket. I want to fix the issue here because the fence is leaning forward. I tried but it's hard to minimize the gap as marked. I am thinking of using an adjustable stringer (usually used for stairs) because those are longer. Please help if you have any better ideas.

[image]

Comment: Maybe the image isn't tall enough, but that gap looks like it's not shrinking as I scan toward the bottom. How wide is the gap at the bottom of the post?

Comment: A photo with some context would be great.

Comment: that looks cursed,  in your land stretching?

Comment: Please take from further away as well.

Comment: Take a picture of the whole section. Include the post on the other side and a couple posts before/after. Obviously, at one time that panel was connected. We need to see what moved to go forward with how to fix.

Comment: @Jasen maybe the proof that the universe is expanding

Comment: A picture of the whole section, from further away, with some context, would help.  

Comment: The fact that is leaning, and thus covering a longer total distance, may in fact be why there is a gap. Straighten it up first to close the gap as much as possible, then come up with some kind of bracket to secure the parts together again. But note that leaning often means the upright is rotting out at the base, so anything done to just strap this together may fail again; consider whether posts are due for replacement.

Comment: Perhaps use a turnbuckle or ratchet strap to pull posts closer together, then fasten panel to post?

Comment: @jsotola  more likely just evidence that the Earth is made of earth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used ratchet straps to pull the posts together and added some screws. It's fixed now. Thank you all for the comments!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can get a 2 x 6 and attach it to the post brackets vertically.  Then you can get some flat, pre-drilled sheet metal plates (one for each rail) and small angle brackets (one per rail) to attach the 2 x 6 to the rails.  Screw them to the post brackets.  Then screw on pickets.

The flat plates can be attached on the same side as the pickets so they will be hidden underneath them.  The angle brackets are for the edge of the 2 x 6 and fence rails for added strength.
Angle brackets & plates are available at Home Depot on the "Door Hardware" aisle.
[image]